# Need some security for uninstallation of an application

Tags: android

I have on security purpose application,i need some security while uninstalling an
  application

please give me some solution.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit what do you mean by 'security'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are aiming to prevent people from uninstalling your application, that can only be accomplished by having your application be burned into the firmware of the device. You cannot even get control when your application is to be uninstalled.